# #define макрос в зависимости от переданного аргумента

Tags: c++, define

Есть 2 функции:

```
UnitAddAbility(unit,id)
UnitRemoveAbility(unit,id)
```

Я бы хотел сделать макрос который в зависимости от переданного аргумента подставит нужную функцию, например так:

`#define UnitSetAbility(unit,id,boolean) UnitAddAbility(unit,id)`

Чтобы в зависимости от агрумента boolean подставилась нужная функция

```
true = UnitAddAbility(unit,id)
false = UnitRemoveAbility(unit,id)
```

Возможно ли как либо это реализовать?

Comment: Что-то типа `#define UnitSetAbility(unit,id,boo) if (boo) UnitAddAbility(unit,id); else UnitRemoveAbility(unit,id);` не годится? Кстати, а чем просто функция `UnitSetAbility` плоха?

Comment: Макрос не нужен, просто функцию сделайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно прибегнуть к оператору `##` для составления имени зависящего от значения параметра:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define UnitSetAbility_true(unit, id) UnitAddAbility(unit, id)
#define UnitSetAbility_false(unit, id) UnitRemoveAbility(unit, id)
#define UnitSetAbility(unit, id, boolean) UnitSetAbility_ ## boolean(unit, id)

void UnitAddAbility(int unit, int id) {
    printf("UnitAddAbility(%d, %d)\n", unit, id);
}

void UnitRemoveAbility(int unit, int id) {
    printf("UnitRemoveAbility(%d, %d)\n", unit, id);
}

int main() {
    UnitSetAbility(1, 2, true);
    UnitSetAbility(3, 4, false);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc temp.c
>
> $ ./a.out 
> UnitAddAbility(1, 2)
> UnitRemoveAbility(3, 4)
> ```

Но зачем это делать? Компилятор выполнит все эти оптимизации без помощи препроцессора, если у него будет такое определение:

```
void UnitSetAbility(int unit, int id, bool set) {
    if (set) {
        UnitAddAbility(unit, id);
    } else {
        UnitRemoveAbility(unit, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, не знал про такой метод.
Насчет вопросов, я не уточнил что делаю это не на c++ а внутри warcraft 3 где основной язык это JASS и просто есть возможность сверху воспользоваться еще и boost препроцессором.
Игре уже 20 лет, да и язык этот оставляет желать лучшего, в связи с чем желательно делать код короче там где это возможно, конечно я могу сделать доп функцию но предположил что этого можно избежать благодаря препроцессору.
Сам я далек от программирования за пределами языка JASS, а про препроцессор узнал случайно, изучив некоторые системы написанные китайскими пользователями.